# How to plot gray level image by matplotlib.pyplot.imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data is 2D image in format of numpy.array. By the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(visu_base)
plt.show()
```

I get a color image from Python. But, how can I show it in gray level?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the api docs of the imshow command[[1](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)]

```
cmap : Colormap, optional, default: None
    If None, default to rc image.cmap value. cmap is ignored when X has RGB(A) information
```

*imshow* takes an optional parameter cmap, which controls the color mapping.

Here can find an overview of the available color mappings defined in matplotlib[[2](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps)]

You could do something like that:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(visu_base, cmap=mpl.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```